# Mysql workbench "Too many objects are selected for auto placement. Select fewer elements to create the EER diagram."

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to generate the ER diagram using Mysql workbench in ubuntu.

> **The database contains 755 Tables**

And the Error message

> **Too many objects are selected for auto placement. Select fewer elements to create the EER diagram.**

Is there any possibility to avoid this error and continue to create Reverse Engineering for all the 755 tables at one shot

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Workbench emits that "Resource Warning" error and then deselects the "Place imported objects on a diagram" option for you. Execute it again (click "Execute") without that option to execute the Reverse Engineering wizard. Then, create a new EER diagram, select all tables (objects) using the "Catalog" tab on the left pane, and then  drag them onto the EER diagram canvas. This will take a few minutes or so to execute. When finished, optionally select "Autolayout" from the "Arrange" navigation menu and then wait another few minutes.

I just tested this with 2000 tables and it works.

Comment: Do you know how to auto arrange tables? Menu/Arrange/Autolayout arranges it, but anyway there are many tables located over other ones.

Comment: @Philip Olson, Yes its worked for me, but  tables are located over other ones , suggest me how to arrange line by rows.

Comment: @Philip Olson Same issue tables are arranged over the other tables. is there a way to increase the cardboard size, on which we are generating a diagram.

Answer (score 9):

By following the @Philip Olson Instruction it resolves my problem, the tables are overlapping due to a large number of tables available in the database with relationships.

I came up with the soliton to tackle this problem :

1 - Click on **Database** > **Reverse Engineer**

[image]

2 - Fillup the connection info > Click on **Next**

[image]

3 - I should complete the all three execution as shown in the below snapshot: Click on **Next**

[image]

4 - Select your database and click on **Next**

[image]

5 - It should again complete the all execution as shown in the snap shot if passed click on **Next**

[image]

6 - On the next screen on **Select Object to Reverse Engineer** uncheck Place imported objects on a diagram if you have large number tables present in your database as shown in the below screen shot and then click on next. Then next screen **should satisfy only first parameter.**

[image]

7 -  Go to EER Diagram Tab, On the left side you will see a tab call Catalog Tree. Select your database, open a tables tranche, select all the tables present under the respective database, and drag and drop on the right hand side diagram board. Now doing this it will create a diagram cluttered like your tables will overlapped on to the another table.

[image]

8 - Now go to the  **Model** > **Diagram Properties and Size** > Select the size of the Diagram from the bottom. As shown in the snap shot below.

[image]

9 - Now go to the **Arrange** menu click on **Auto Layout** TADA. Your EER Diagram with proper alignment is ready for you.